# Vue file organisation and models with various states

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

We have a system where clients can place orders, however they need to generate quotes first.
How we have set this up in our models is that an order has a status quote and a status complete.

Our front end is organised in such a way that each model in our back end is its own module with its own pages and components nested within that module.

I would like to have an orders index view and a quotes index view. With regards to the organisation, would it be more correct for both indexes to be separate pages nested in the order module or would it be better for quotes be its own module?

Comment: If a `quote` is something different than `order` - then yes, they should be in separate modules, and their indexes must reside in the corresponding module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is really a matter of preference, there's no right or wrong way. The way I understand it there are two entities in backend, Orders and Quotes so according to your already established organisation logic, this should be done as two separate "modules".

BTW, not sure what you mean by "module", I suppose it means a directory which contains all files related to some functionality, and maybe it seems like an overkill in this case, but consistency is more important than convenience :)